# how to fix script tag parse error on IOS Safari

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
<script type="application/ld+json">{\"@context\":\"\"}</script>

<script type="application/ld+json">{"@context":""}</script>
```

When try to add the *scripts* to the DOM with JQuery, on IOS Safari - it returns the following error message.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'. Parse error.
```

How can we get it parsed?

Comment: Tested both on my chrome and safari,seems good

Comment: did you tried by debugging iPhone